# Application Insights Log4j filter by log file name

Tags: java, azure, log4j, azure-application-insights

I've got an Application Insights resource in Azure. In our Java application, we have a log4j.xml file which writes to multiple log files depending on the service name.

I'm adding the Application Insights appender to the logging, and I'm able to see all the logs of the different log files in the Application Insights resource. However, I'm unable to filter by the log file name in Application Insights, so the trace logs are not useful.

Is there a way to get the log file name into the logging event properties? This way, in AppInsights we would be able to filter by log file name, and read them as if we had the log files there.

Edit:
our log4j.xml looks something like this, with aiAppender in it for application insights

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
<appender name="fileout" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyyMMdd"/>
    <param name="file" value="${app.install.home}/log/${app.server.name}-${app.service.process.host}.log"/>
    <param name="append" value="true"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %5p [%t] (%C) - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
</appender>
<appender name="aiAppender" 
    class="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.log4j.v1_2.ApplicationInsightsAppender">
</appender>    
<root> 
    <priority value ="INFO" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="fileout"/>
    <appender-ref ref="aiAppender" />
</root>
```

Comment: Do you use some kind of file appender for generating the log files? If so, appenders do not aware of other appenders and there's no simple way for telling AI appender the file that the event belongs to.
Nevertheless, you can group by 'device_Id' property which is the machine name.

Comment: @yonisha See my edit for the log4j.xml example. We're using the DailyRollingFileAppender. All the services are on the same machine so device_Id filter would not be helpful for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a [TelemetryInitializer](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/microsoft/applicationinsights/extensibility/TelemetryInitializer.java) to add the service name to the telemetry properties, which can be used for grouping.

You telemetry initializer should look like the following:

```
public class ServiceNameInitializer implements TelemetryInitializer {
    @Override
    public void initialize(Telemetry telemetry) {
        if (telemetry instanceof TraceTelemetry) {
            telemetry.getProperties().put("ServiceName", ServiceNameFromConfigurationOrProcessName);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the condition can be removed - this will add the property to all telemetry types.

Once you've implemented the initializer, add it to the [configuration file](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-java-get-started/#3-add-an-application-insights-xml-file), inside the *TelemetryInitializers* element:

```
<TelemetryInitializers>
    .
    .
    <Add type="your.initializer.package.ServiceNameInitializer"/>
</TelemetryInitializers>
```

Comment: That is exactly what we were needing! Worked easily just as suggested. Thank you!